# Side NavBar: imposible to change height and width

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm using this Pure CSS hamburger menu code: https://codepen.io/Joanc/pen/XYYZdE

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  /*make it look decent enough*/
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
  
  overflow-x: hidden; /*needed because hiding the menu on the right side is not perfect*/
}

a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover
{
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /*hide this*/
  z-index: 2; /*and place it over the hamburger*/
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*Just a quick hamburger*/
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/*Transform all the slices of hamburger into a crossmark*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*But let's hide the middle one*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*Make this absolute positioned at the top left of the screen*/
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  right: -100px;
  
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /*to stop flickering of text in safari*/
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*And let's fade it in from the left*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--    Made by Erik Terwan    -->
<!--   24th of November 2015   -->
<!--        MIT License        -->
<nav role='navigation'>
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    
    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank"><li>Show me more</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

After endless tryouts, I find myself completely unable to set the height of the side navbar to 100% and change the width according to the screen size.

What am I missing? What cannot I see? I would extremely appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you in advance and cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  right: -100px;
  
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
```

if you use: `vh - vw` instead of the `%` everything should work fine.

this works because it'll only fill up 100% of the height or 50% of the viewport, and not the parent.

Comment: What I see by using `height =100vh` is that the navbar creates an unnecessary scroll down. Is a way to solve that? Again, thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Yes there is a way to solve that.. you can use `position: fixed;`

Comment: Great! So simple once you know ;) Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `height: 100vh` to your `#menu` css tells the container to fill 100% of the viewport height. If you change from the fixed-width of `width: 300px` to `width: 25vw` for example, your menu will only ever occupy 25% of the viewport width.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  /*make it look decent enough*/
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
  
  overflow-x: hidden; /*needed because hiding the menu on the right side is not perfect*/
}

a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover
{
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /*hide this*/
  z-index: 2; /*and place it over the hamburger*/
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*Just a quick hamburger*/
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/*Transform all the slices of hamburger into a crossmark*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*But let's hide the middle one*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*Make this absolute positioned at the top left of the screen*/
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  right: -100px;
  
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /*to stop flickering of text in safari*/
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*And let's fade it in from the left*/
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--    Made by Erik Terwan    -->
<!--   24th of November 2015   -->
<!--        MIT License        -->
<nav role='navigation'>
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    
    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank"><li>Show me more</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What I see by using `height =100vh` is that the navbar creates an unnecessary scroll down. 
With the width what I've been trying to use is the CSS media queries and delete the value `width: 300px`but it seems that there is no action. 

Any advise? Again, thank you a lot in advance!